# from java EE Send HTML data through PHP without changing using JSON objects

Tags: php, html, json

I have to send a response to the frontend that contain a message and HTML code as below.

```
    01|<form method="post" action="https://sample.php" id="frm_submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="Name" value="name">
    <input type="hidden" name="Pass" value="pass">
</form><script>document.getElementById('frm_submit').submit();</script>
```

This message is sent to a PHP page. PHP send it to front end as JSON object,

```
$res = getBackendRespons($urlPart);
 $outObj = array('success' => res[0], 'url' => $res[1]);
echo CJSON::encode($outObj);
```

So the frontend receive,

```
{"success":true,"url":"    \t\t\t\t    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t    \t\t\t\t\t
<form method=\"post\" action=\"https:\/\/sample.php\" id=\"frm_submit\">    \t\t\t\t    \t\t\t\t    \t\t\t\t    \t\t\t\t\t
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"Name\" value=\"name\">    \t\t\t\t    \t\t\t\t\t
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"Pass\" value=\"pass\">    \t\t\t\t    \t\t\t\t\t
        \t\t\t\t\t<\/form>    \t\t\t\t\t
    <script>    \t\t\t\t\t\tdocument.getElementById('frm_submit').submit();    \t\t\t\t\t<\/script>    \t\t\t\t\t"}
```

Here the HTML code cannot be displayed properly. Because it has changed when passed through PHP. How to make sure the HTML code is not changed until the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending a String or URL encoded string from Java EE doesn't work because some values are changed when passed through PHP server. 
So the best way I found was to use Base64 encoding from the Java EE side and the PHP doesn't change the string.

On the front end decode and display the code as follow,

```
<script>
function b64DecodeUnicode(str) {        
    return decodeURIComponent(atob(str).split('').map(function(c) {
        return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }).join(''));
}
var words = b64DecodeUnicode(base64_encoded_string_goes_here);
document.write(words);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have to `decode()` the JSON before echo your JSON because `encode()` scape your html to not crash with your quotation marks or slashes.

Them you have to access your JSON vars propertly. It must looks like:

```
$outObj = CJSON::decode($outObj);
echo $outObj->success; // To access to yor boolean value
echo $outObj->url; // To access to yor HTML
```